# Race condition and primary key constraint violated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this multithreaded java application. Each thread inserts records in employee_hist table if the employee id does not exist.

The old buggy app first

1. runs a SQL query to check if the employee id exist in the employee_hist table.
2. If the count is 0, then only it inserts the record in the history table.

Since this is multi-threaded, two parallel threads A and B can create a problem. Thread A checks if the employee id exist, if not it inserts the record. The B thread also did the checking at the same time as A, but then A is the first one to finish the insertion. Now B, when it tries to insert the same employee id, it will complain that employee id already exists and constraint violation error is thrown!

To fix this, I replaced the old 2 step process  with just 1 step
`INSERT INTO employee_hist (emp_id, description) SELECT 1000, 'bush' from dual a  where not exists (select 1 from employee_hist b where b.employee_id in(1000));`

Meaning no insertion will happen if the record already exist. All this is done in one single statement.

Unfortunately, it does not work. I still get constraint violation error. I'm wondering how that is possible. What did I miss?

Comment: Checking in advance is a bad practice. If the key is synthetic you should use an IDENTITY KEY or a SEQUENCE (there won't ever be conflicts); if the key is natural... well, there's no valid reason to use natural keys nowadays.

Comment: I didnt get that at all.

How can I not check the presence of employee id in the hist table.Remember employee_hist table is the child table.Employee is the parent table.

Comment: In simple terms. How are you deciding on the value of "emp_id" when inserting? Do you 1) Let the database automatically pick the next available value, or 2) You get the value from the outside world (in a form, according to a rule, etc.)? You should typically be doing #1; the "emp_id" column should be defined as IDENTITY, or you could use an old SEQUENCE for it; your choice.

Comment: employee id already exist. Only those employee that has been marked for archiving is moved to history. So yes,employee id is an identity column in employee table...but in employee history it is a foreign key.   So..i am still confused about your response

Comment: You didn't provide detail in the question to clearly indicate which constraint is violated.  That will help drive a solution. 1) Provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements, with constraints, in text form and which can be executed without errors.  2) Show the exact `INSERT` statement that leads to a constraint violation. 3) Indicate the exact / complete error (which should show the constraint) generated by your insert.  It's tough to answer when almost no usable detail is provided.  Don't leave out detail.  Provide all the SQL needed to produce the error, even if the error isn't always generated.

Comment: You could **use** the fact a constraint violation is thrown to **re-do** your unit of work (rollback your current transaction, and start over from the beginning).

Comment: Would the [merge](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement) statement of oracle be a solution? It itself does an insert or update, depending on the existence of the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the number of steps, it is the read consistency.  If we imagine a timeline of events (but slowed down incredibly)

9:00am:  Session 1 insert EMP=100 if not exists
=> No row found so goes ahead and inserts

9:01am:  Session 2 insert EMP=100 if not exists
=> No row i is found (because 9:00am has not committed yet)
=> commences insert (and will block, aka, wait)

9:02am: Session 1 commits

9:03am: Session 2 can now proceed but insert will fail with PK violation because there is now a row with EMP=100

Normally to handle these situations we lock "something", eg it might be a parent department record etc, ie, something that sits above the employee history that can be used to serialise access.

However, if it is indeed this single tbale, then serialising on non-existent rows is non-trivial because there isn't "something" to lock.  In this case, you  can use DBMS_LOCK to synthesize a lock that each session must acquire, eg (psuedocode)

- dbms_lock.request(id=> employee ID, mode => exclusive)
- insert with not-exists check
- commit;